# Unittest compare a float is in range of

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

i'am searching for a Unittest in python that checks if the returned float from a function is in between 0-100.

Couldn't find something on the internet yet.

Thx

Answer (score -1):

Apart from the obvious raw assertions with inequalities, if your float is part of a larger structure (eg a dict or a list) that you want to match, then one option could define a matcher class using `__eq__` like:

```
class FloatInRange:
    def __init__(self, min: float, max: float):
        self.min = min
        self.max = max

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other >= self.min and other < self.max

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<FloatInRange({self.min}, {self.max})>"


def test_float_in_range():
    assert {'foo': 60.0} == {'foo': FloatInRange(0, 100)}
```

Comment: Don't abuse `__eq__` like this. Equality is supposed to be reflexive, symmetric, and transitive, and you definition is none of these.

Comment: @chepner I agree in principle (although it is symmetric).  However, Python's own `unitest.mock.ANY` is not transitive yet it remains useful in tests as a similar matcher https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#any